# Error when change domain in Symfony 1.4 project

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

looking from some master on this.

I have my symfony 1.4 project in one domain working perfectly, now I changed the project as it is to another domain ( the same but finishing in .net instead of .com ). Now the home works but all other pages or link destinations to the same page show error "page not found". Weird is that when I use the extension frontend.php or index.php before the routing it works fine. ( in dev mode all works... ).

Of course I cleared the cache lots of times...

Any idea? Why changing domain the routing stopped working?

I also changed all htaccess extensions in the new project...

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds link the RewriteRules are missing.  Check the server configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need mod_rewrite enabled on your web server and your .htaccess file should look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```